# WidgetKit - Is there a way to section the data in intent handling during edit widget

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

This is how we provide "edit widget" feature in `WidgetKit`, by using an intent definition file.

### Intent definition file

[image]

### Outcome during Edit widget

[image]

---

To provide a list of selection, during intent handling (When the edit widget page is tap), this is our code.

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    func provideWidgetItemOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<WidgetItem>?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
        var widgetItems = [WidgetItem]()
        
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "1", display: "Visit grandma"))
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "2", display: "Don't forget milk"))
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "3", display: "Buy socks"))
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "4", display: "Pick up laundry"))
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "5", display: "Reply email"))
        widgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "6", display: "Meeting at 3pm"))
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: widgetItems)
        
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        return self
    }
    
}
```

and this is the outcome

### Outcome during Intent handling

[image]

I was wondering, is there a way to create multiple section on the UI?

For instance,

```
[Personal]
"Visit grandma"
"Don't forget milk"
"Buy socks"
"Pick up laundry"

[Work]
"Reply email"
"Meeting at 3pm"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    func provideWidgetItemOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<WidgetItem>?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
        
        var personalWidgetItems = [WidgetItem]()
        var workWidgetItems = [WidgetItem]()
        
        personalWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "1", display: "Visit grandma"))
        personalWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "2", display: "Don't forget milk"))
        personalWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "3", display: "Buy socks"))
        personalWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "4", display: "Pick up laundry"))
        workWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "5", display: "Reply email"))
        workWidgetItems.append(WidgetItem(identifier: "6", display: "Meeting at 3pm"))
        
        let personalSection = INObjectSection(title: "Personal", items: personalWidgetItems)
        let workSection = INObjectSection(title: "Work", items: workWidgetItems)
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(sections: [personalSection, workSection])
        
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        return self
    }
    
}
```

, and here's the outcome.

[image]